# Can't get images from instagram posted with tag name by another person

Tags: image, api, get, instagram, instagram-api

I used the below url, I received the pictures which I posted with the specified tag name. But I can't get images posted with tag name by another person.
Please Help Me.
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=MYACCESS-TOKEN.

Answer (score 0):

You are in Sandbox mode, so it will return only media from your sandbox authorized user, here is information about this:

> As another example, let's consider an endpoint that returns a list of
>   media: /tags/{tag-name}/media/recent. The response returned by this
>   endpoint will contain only media with the given tag, as expected. But
>   instead of returning media from any public Instagram user, it will
>   return only media that belongs to your sandbox users, restricted to
>   the last 20 for each user.

Here is the link to more details about Sandbox mode: https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem. But Thanks for your response.